# Amount by which to increase checkpoint_segments (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, logs, checkpoint, logging

In my postgresql log, I see statements such as `checkpoints are occurring too frequently (26 seconds apart)`. Currently in the conf, `checkpoint_segments` are 32, `checkpoint_timeout` is 15 mins and `checkpoint_completion_target` is 0.9.

I've seen many suggestions that I need to increase my `checkpoint_segments`. But they don't talk about *by how much*? Around 6GBs of postgresql log is generated daily (it's a write heavy chat application).

How do I go about tuning `checkpoint_segments` to a higher value?

Comment: You may find some interesting bits in here: http://anarazel.de/talks/pgconf-nyc-2016-04-20/io.pdf